# Saving source line in property using CSV Helper

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I have this simple class

```
public class Data
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
 //  public string? OriginalRecord { get; set; }
}
```

This is my data file:

```
32,Foo
45,Bar
```

Reading is done like this

```
    using (var reader = new StreamReader("file.csv"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(streamReader, new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) { HasHeaderRecord = false }))
    {
        var records = csv.GetRecords<Data>();
    }
```

Now, my question is this: is there anyway that I can populate the `OriginalRecord` property with data used to create the record (`32,Foo` for the first record, and `45,Bar` for the second record)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Convert` in a `ClassMap` to get the `RawRecord` value.

```cs
void Main()
{
    using (var reader = new StringReader("32,Foo\n45,Bar"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) { HasHeaderRecord = false }))
    {      
        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<DataMap>();
        var records = csv.GetRecords<Data>().Dump();
    }
}

public sealed class DataMap : ClassMap<Data>
{
    public DataMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.Id).Index(0);
        Map(x => x.Name).Index(1);
        Map(x => x.OriginalRecord).Convert(args => args.Row.Parser.RawRecord);
    }
}

public class Data
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string? OriginalRecord { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do manually get the fields,

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "file.csv")))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) { HasHeaderRecord = false }))
{
    var records = new List<Data>();
    //If you have header, we need to skip one row then read the header
    //csv.Read();
    //csv.ReadHeader();
    while (csv.Read())
    {
        var record = new Data()
        {
            //Id = csv.GetField<int>("Id"), when you have header
            Id = csv.GetField<int>(0),
            Name = csv.GetField(1),
            OriginalRecord = csv.Parser.RawRecord
        };
        records.Add(record);
    }
}
```